# Prove that $\{A\rightarrow \sim B, B, C \vee A\} \vdash C$ in this proof system

Tags: logic

I have this proof system:

$$Ax: \alpha \rightarrow (\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$$ 
$$IR: \frac{\alpha \vee \lnot \beta, \beta }{\alpha} \space \space \frac{\alpha \rightarrow \beta , \lnot \beta}{\lnot \alpha}$$

And I can't see how it is possible to prove that:

$\{A\rightarrow  \lnot B, B, C \vee A\} \vdash C$

I thought may be:

1. $A\rightarrow  \lnot B$ (assumption)
2. $B$ (assumption)
3. $\lnot A$ (inference rule #2 by lines 1,2)

And I do not know how to continue from here, I hope someone could help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have some sort of $\lnot \lnot A = A$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Now you have $\lnot A$ take the third assumption $(C \lor A)$ and because of your first IR you get $C$ (using the double negation rule which should be derived as a logic theorem of your system)

Comment: But the second IR asks for $\alpha \vee \lnot \beta$, so how can I use $C\vee A$?

Comment: @NoahLevy if you are allowed to use the double negation rule then you have that $A \equiv \lnot \lnot A$, so in this case $\alpha$ would be $C$ and $\beta$ would be $\lnot A$ and then you can apply your first IR. But I have to appologize because I thought you could derive the double negation rule within your system but now I'm not sure, it seems quite weak to let you do that